# LINQ - Where not exists

Tags: linq, exists

What is the equivalent of following statement in LINQ:

```
Select t1.appname, t1.julianDte, t1.cat 
From table1 t1 
Where NOT EXISTS 
   ( Select * 
     from table t2 
     where t1.cat = t2.cat AND t2.julianDte < t1.julianDte )
```

Answer (score 62):

Try this `Not Any` pattern.

```
var query = db.table1
.Where(t1 => !db.table2
  .Any(t2 => t2.cat == t1.cat && t2.julianDte < t1.julianDte)
);
```

Comment: I would make sure to comment this with a `//where NOT EXISTS` and try to format it `!db.table2.Any...` so that the `!` is on the same line as `Any`.  Often LINQ is fairly self describing, but this is a case I think a comment would be greatly appreciated but future devs coming across your code.

Comment: @AaronLS it's an interesting philosophical question... How well commented should syntax demonstrations be?  I clearly didn't need to put that comment in for the benefit of the asker, as he already used the sql form in the question.

Comment: I wasn't critiquing your answer, I was making a general suggestion for anyone who uses this code, and thanks it was useful.

Answer (score 11):

Query syntax version of @Amy B's answer (with !Any inverted to All):

```
from t1 in db.Table1
where db.Table2.All(t2 => t1.cat != t2.cat || t2.julianDte >= t1.julianDte)
select new
{
    t1.appname,
    t1.julianDte,
    t1.cat
};
```

Comment: how well does that translate to sql?  In my experience, "OR" is to be avoided.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what about "OR" would make it more dangerous than "AND"?

Comment: OR tends to interfere with the use of indexes. Find people who live on 3rd street AND are plumbers... In this case, an index of people by the street they live on is highly useful. Find people who live on 3rd street OR are plumbers... In this case, an index of people by the street they live on is much less useful.

Answer (score 1):

```
from t1 in Context.table1DbSet
let ok = 
    (from t2 in Context.table2DbSet 
     where t2.Idt1 = t1.Idt1 && t1.DateValid.HasValue
    ).Any()
where 
   t1.Active
   && !ok
```