# How to SELECT WHERE NOT EXIST using LINQ?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I have to list all "**shift**" data to be assigned to an "**employee**" but shift data must not be included if it is already existing in employee's data. Let's see the image sample.

[image: No filtering yet]

This query solves the problem. I found this here:
[Scott's Blog](http://miniburb.wordpress.com/2007/05/31/sql-outer-join-vs-where-not-in-vs-not-exists/)

```
select * from shift where not exists 
(select 1 from employeeshift where shift.shiftid = employeeshift.shiftid
and employeeshift.empid = 57);
```

Let's see the result:

[image: Filtered]

Now my question is, how could I make this in linQ ? I'm using entity framework.
Hope someone could help. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: you could simply do a join ... if the right-record does not exist, the left-record should not be included

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair Can you make some example? I've done a lot of joining but I didn't get the right one.

Comment: You can reffer to other SO topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/899090/linq-where-not-exists for **WHERE NOT IN** clause in Linq

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ - Where not exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/899090/linq-where-not-exists)

Answer (score 117, accepted):

```
from s in context.shift
where !context.employeeshift.Any(es=>(es.shiftid==s.shiftid)&&(es.empid==57))
select s;
```

Comment: "&&es.empid=57" must be inside "(es.shiftid==s.shiftid)". it work but it doesn't return complete data, some data are missing.

Answer (score 32):

The outcome sql will be different but the result should be the same:

```
var shifts = Shifts.Where(s => !EmployeeShifts.Where(es => es.ShiftID == s.ShiftID).Any());
```

Comment: You should always use `Any()` instead of `Count()` to determine if there _are_ results...

Comment: you should use !.Any() instead of count. If there's none the performance will be the same but in all cases where there' more than 1 element any will be faster since it stops the iteration after the first element is found

Comment: you lost empid = 57 condition?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I suggest to modify a bit your sql query:

```
 select * from shift 
 where shift.shiftid not in (select employeeshift.shiftid from employeeshift 
                             where employeeshift.empid = 57);
```

This query provides same functionality.
If you want to get the same result with LINQ, you can try this code:

```
//Variable dc has DataContext type here
//Here we get list of ShiftIDs from employeeshift table
List<int> empShiftIds = dc.employeeshift.Where(p => p.EmpID = 57).Select(s => s.ShiftID).ToList();

//Here we get the list of our shifts
List<shift> shifts = dc.shift.Where(p => !empShiftIds.Contains(p.ShiftId)).ToList();
```

Comment: You sql query work perfectly. But in linq, I'm fine with single query. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see here, most solutions are based of an IN or NOT IN clause.
I would argue that a Left join and where ID is null type of solution is better.

This is what I am using.

```
var linqQuery = 
from shift in context.Shift.Where(x=> x.IfYouHaveMoreConditions == true)
from employeeShift in context.EmployeeShift.Where(x=> shift.ShiftId == x.ShiftId ) /* this will become your left join condition */
where employeeShift.ShiftId == null /*this will create a compiler warning, because the ID cannot be null, but will still work and compile and is necessary*/
select shift;
```

Then this will result in the following SQL:

```
SELECT shift.* FROM shift
LEFT OUTER JOIN emlpoyeeshift ON shift.shiftid = employeeshift.shiftid
WHERE emlployeeshift.shiftid IS NULL
```

and then bob is your uncle

Answer (score -1):

How about..

```
var result = (from s in context.Shift join es in employeeshift on s.shiftid equals es.shiftid where es.empid == 57 select s)
```

Edit: This will give you shifts where there is an associated employeeshift (because of the join). For the "not exists" I'd do what @ArsenMkrt or @hyp suggest

Comment: Yup, plus I realised I'm not actaully answering the right question!

Comment: yea, because the result should be result-set, you are getting bool value

Answer (score -2):

```
        Dim result2 = From s In mySession.Query(Of CSucursal)()
                      Where (From c In mySession.Query(Of CCiudad)()
                             From cs In mySession.Query(Of CCiudadSucursal)()
                             Where cs.id_ciudad Is c
                             Where cs.id_sucursal Is s
                             Where c.id = IdCiudad
                             Where s.accion <> "E" AndAlso s.accion <> Nothing
                             Where cs.accion <> "E" AndAlso cs.accion <> Nothing
                             Select c.descripcion).Single() Is Nothing
                      Where s.accion <> "E" AndAlso s.accion <> Nothing
                      Select s.id, s.Descripcion
```