# Select rows by date and exclude row that has latest record

Tags: sql, linq

I have a table `Orders`

```
Name             DateOrdered
louie            01/50/2017
jonathan         02/06/2016
prince           05/23/2016
louie            07/02/2016
```

i want to select records by year, for example 2016 but i want the result to show only `jonathan` and `prince` because `louie` has a latest record in 2017, how to query this? thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to SELECT WHERE NOT EXIST using LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9031008/how-to-select-where-not-exist-using-linq)

Comment: I have to check it in the same table

Answer (score 2):

Try the below sample query.

```
 SELECT * from Orders WHERE YEAR(DateOrdered) = '2016' AND name != 
'louie';
```

Answer (score 0):

With subquery. For example in transact sql ( sybase ase)

```
Select from orders a
Where DateOrdered  != (select min(dateordered) from orders b 
                       where convert(char(04),dateordered)=convert(char(04),a.dateordered))
```

The convert function is to compare year part from field dateordered

I hope it will be useful

Answer (score 0):

If you are sorting the query using date below query can remove the top row:

```
declare @Total INT;
declare @requiredRows INT;
Select @Total=  Count (*) From Orders
SET @requiredRows = @Total -1;

Select * From(
Select TOP (@requiredRows) * From Orders
Order By DateOrdered ASC) As tbl
Order By DateOrdered DESC
```

You can use 'YEAR' function to extract year from the dateOrdered column