# LINQ where db table does not contain in memory list elements

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I have seen [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183791/how-would-you-do-a-not-in-query-with-linq) [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899090/linq-where-not-exists) [Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9031008/how-to-select-where-not-exist-in-linq) but they do not produce the same results when the filtering list is in memory.

I have a list of Ids. I want to remove any IDs that exists in the database, so that I am left with a list of IDs that need to be added. In other words, I need to perform a `where not in` SQL query, using Linq-To-Entities. The problem is, instead of producing that SQL, these methods each produce a SQL query *per list item*.

`var providerIds = new [] {"1130", "1", "16"};`

**Method 1**:

```
var missingProviders = (from provider in providerIds
                        where !JobProviders.Any(p => p.JobProviderID == provider)
                        select provider).ToList();
```

**Method 2**:

```
var missingProviders = (from provider in providerIds
                        where !(from p in JobProviders select p.JobProviderID).Contains(provider)
                        select provider).ToList();
```

Is there a way to structure the LINQ query such that it produces the intended `not in` form, or are these the only solutions?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this problem?

Comment: @Arthur, No, I haven't. I am not using LINQ because it appears that there is no way to do this.

Answer (score -1):

What about something like

```
var providersInDb = (from provider in JobProviders
                     where providerIds.Contains(provider.JobProviderID)
                     select provider.JobProviderID).ToList();

var missingProviders = providerIds.Where(p => !providersInDb.Contains(p))
```

Comment: That's what I am doing for now, actually, but the issue is that I am doubling up a lot of work. If the list of `providerIds` and `providersInDb` are both large, then the DB is doing the work of the lookup, sending back a large list, and then the client is filtering it as well. Ideally, the large `providerIds` list would go to the DB, which would do all the filtering, and just send back the `missingProviders`.

Comment: So testing this with a list of 1k, there is a HUGE performance difference between this, and a `not in` query for SQL.

Answer (score -1):

Tricky.  I don't have my tools in front of me, so I don't know how this will pan out exactly.

```
var dbProviderIds = JobProviders.Select(p => p.JobProviderId);
var allProviders = dbProviderIds.Union(providerIds).Distinct();
var missing = allProviders.Except(dbProviderIds);
```

On the DB, get all the provider Ids, then combine that with the in-memory ones.  Then remove the ones that are known on the database.

Comment: This has the same flaw as the previous answer: it is terrible for performance to pull **all** the Ids from the database to perform this step. The entire purpose is to avoid doing so, by sending a list to the database, and getting back only what is needed. It also does not answer the question of getting LINQ to produce the `not in` SQL query.